# Code folding in JSFiddle

Tags: jsfiddle

Is it possible to enable code folding in JSFiddle? I've found that long JavaScript files can become unwieldy without code folding.

(I'm referring to the feature in Geany or the Eclipse IDE that makes it possible to collapse text that is surrounded by curly braces.)

Comment: As of Feb 2016, there is no feature like that. (Sidenote : will be great to have this feature. Alternatively :  Need to write chrome extension (ofcourse this is hack) like this one : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-code-folding/iokmjnihlfnchffcmjihafillepmhogk?hl=en )

Answer (score 1):

On [January 2018, this feature moved to development in their trello board](https://trello.com/c/U8l1Cv4u/50-code-folding).

[image]

And the [comment about starting development](https://trello.com/c/U8l1Cv4u/50-code-folding#action-5a5784fb2cc944bd12f012be):

> [**Oskar Krawczyk**](https://trello.com/oskarkrawczyk): moved this card from Accepted to In Development

- This comment was made by (one of) the creator(s) of JSFiddle:
  [image]

So I guess we should be seeing it in the near future!